# What are some good GitExtensions alternatives for Linux?

Tags: linux, git

I want a tool for Linux, similar to Git Extension, that has the following features:

- pull and push code by using right click on the root folder of the project
- the ability to see the changes and to stage and unstage
- the ability to stash and unstash changes.

Comment: Starred, good question. I don't think that tool exists.

Comment: A stand-alone tool is OK? Git Cola should cover that. Or shall it integrate with your favorite file manager? Then please [edit] your question and specify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Visual Studio Code and the popular community extension [GitLens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens).

Tagline:

> Supercharge the Git capabilities built into Visual Studio Code — Visualize code authorship at a glance via Git blame annotations and code lens, seamlessly navigate and explore Git repositories, gain valuable insights via powerful comparison commands, and so much more.

It gives you a complex editor view, and a right-click menu like this:

[image]